# Undefined Method For Email Attribute

Tags: ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-5, actionmailer

I am trying to send a bunch of individual emails to multiple recipients at once. How I am tying to do this is the user will download an excel spreadsheet and fill it in with a bunch of names and respective emails and then uploads that spreadsheet to the app. The app creates guestlist objects with the fields filled in and I am wanting to send an email to each person in the guestlist.

The importing of the guestlist is working, however I cant seem to get my mailer working to send the emails.

*UPDATE*

The Mailer now send the same amount of emails as the number of people in the guestlist but all the emails are being sent to one of the email addresses.

Code for the mailer:

```
def guestlist_email()
 Guestlist.all.each { |guestlist| mail(to: guestlist.email) }
end
```

Code for the Controller:

```
def import
 Guestlist.import(params[:file])
 Guestlist.all.each do |guestlist|
  GuestMailer.with(guestlist: @guestlist).guestlist_email.deliver_now
 end
 redirect_to guestlists_url, notice: "Guest-list Successfully 
 Imported."
end
```

If you need any more pieces of code I will upload.

Here is the log from terminal.

```
  (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
  Guestlist Create (3.5ms)  INSERT INTO "guestlists" ("id", "name", "email", "response", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 3], ["name", "Ryan Neill"], ["email", "ryan.neill11@gmail.com"], ["response", "no"], ["created_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.133312"], ["updated_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.133312"]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
   (3.1ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
  Guestlist Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "guestlists".* FROM "guestlists" WHERE "guestlists"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:18
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
  Guestlist Create (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "guestlists" ("id", "name", "email", "response", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 2], ["name", "robiin"], ["email", "robinbrink43@gmail.com"], ["response", "yes"], ["created_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.147201"], ["updated_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.147201"]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
   (3.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
  Guestlist Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "guestlists".* FROM "guestlists" WHERE "guestlists"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:18
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
  Guestlist Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "guestlists" ("id", "name", "email", "response", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 1], ["name", "ryan"], ["email", "ryan.neill11@gmail.com"], ["response", ""], ["created_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.159332"], ["updated_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.159332"]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
   (3.8ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/guestlists
  Guestlist Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "guestlists".* FROM "guestlists" ORDER BY "guestlists"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/mailers/guest_mailer.rb:11
  Rendering guest_mailer/guestlist_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered guest_mailer/guestlist_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.0ms)
  Guestlist Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "guestlists".* FROM "guestlists" ORDER BY "guestlists"."id" ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 1]]
  ↳ app/mailers/guest_mailer.rb:12
  Rendering guest_mailer/guestlist_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered guest_mailer/guestlist_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (1.1ms)
  Guestlist Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "guestlists".* FROM "guestlists" ORDER BY "guestlists"."id" ASC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 2]]
  ↳ app/mailers/guest_mailer.rb:13
  Rendering guest_mailer/guestlist_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer
  Rendered guest_mailer/guestlist_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)
GuestMailer#guestlist_email: processed outbound mail in 108.8ms
Sent mail to ryan.neill11@gmail.com (3768.3ms)
Date: Tue, 01 Oct 2019 16:43:31 +0200
From: rsvpeasy01@gmail.com
To: ryan.neill11@gmail.com
Message-ID: <5d9366134463d_7c6d3fdbf4e367045421e@Ryans-MacBook-Air.local.mail>
Subject: Guestlist email
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>

  </body>
</html>

Completed 302 Found in 3969ms (ActiveRecord: 20.3ms)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when your import method executes? Please post the output of your logs - does the system try and send the e-mail and fail?

Comment: I think your third line of the guestlist_email method is breaking - you already have a variable called guestlist so don't need to use @guestlist - try getting rid of `@guestlist = params[:guestlist]` and changing the next line to `mail(to: guestlist.email)`

Comment: @Mark undefined method '`email' for nil:NilClass' is the error i get for the line 'mail(to: @guestlist.email)' - that is why i put in the '@guestlist = params[:guestlist]' but it still doesn't work without it

Comment: Have you tried my suggestions in my second comment? You're assigning @guestlist to your params (which in your mailer will be nil)

Comment: Will write out a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
def guestlist_email()
 Guestlist.all.each { |guestlist| mail(to: guestlist.email) }
end
```

If the above code is only sending an e-mail to the first guestlist, it strongly suggests the other e-mails are wrong. The below code is identical to the above but carries out each e-mail explicitly:

```
def guestlist_email()
  mail(to: Guestlist.first.email )
  mail(to: Guestlist.second.email )
  mail(to: Guestlist.third.email )
end
```

If one of those works and the others don't, the problem has to be with your Guestlist emails stored for your second and third guestlists

SECOND EDIT:

Try changing your import method to:

```
def import
  Guestlist.import(params[:file])
    Guestlist.all.each do |guestlist|
      GuestMailer.with(guestlist: @guestlist, event: @event).guestlist_email.deliver_now
    end
  redirect_to guestlists_url, notice: "Guestlists imported."
end
```

Comment: This fixed the error but is only sending one email to the first person on the list

Comment: Do you think it could be how I am calling the mailer in the controller?

Comment: Are you definitely saving all of your guestlists? The above code should iterate through every Guestlist - what does `Guestlist.count` return?

Comment: Hi @Mark, sorry for the delayed response but I did 'Guestlist.count' and it returned 3 which was the correct number.

Comment: If you've three guestlist records then the above code should send them to all from what I can see

Comment: (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
  Guestlist Create (3.5ms)  INSERT INTO "guestlists" ("id", "name", "email", "response", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["id", 3], ["name", "Ryan Neill"], ["email", "ryan.neill11@gmail.com"], ["response", "no"], ["created_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.133312"], ["updated_at", "2019-10-01 14:43:31.133312"]]
  ↳ app/models/guestlist.rb:20
   (3.1ms)  commit transaction - this is the terminal output when adding a guestlist (i could only add one for space purposes but this does happen for each item)

Comment: With the above said it seem that each item is being added to the database. I did try the other option you sent me and still only sent to the first one and now I am really confused. Appreciate all the help

Comment: Is there an equivalent log for sending the e-mails? The bit you pasted confirms that one account is being created

Comment: I will addd it above - this is using the second mailer action you suggested

Comment: Would it be possible to rather have a button to call the mailer in a separate action?

Comment: I notice from the server logs only one of the records is created with a 'response' value of yes, is this being used to determine e-mail sending?

Comment: No, The guests are added with no initial response and then they make their appropriate response after the email.

Comment: Sorry I can't think of anything else that would stop the mails sending :(

Comment: No worries, appreciate all the help - definite progress has been made so thank you

Comment: Hi @mark, thanks for still giving it a go :) So the new edit now sends 3 emails (the length of the guestlist) however it is only sending to the last email on the list.

Answer (score 0):

It may be more readable if you separate out the spreadsheet import functionality from the emailing functionality.   So first import the entire excel sheet.  Then loop through the data from the table and send one mail at a time.

Your loop should be something like:

```
class SendWeeklySummary
  def run
    User.find_each do |user|
      UserMailer.with(user: user).weekly_summary.deliver_now
    end
  end
end
```

from

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html